# @Named + @RequestScoped not working in JSF 2.0 with JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cdi

I have a working `@ManagedBean` which I'd like to substitute with a `@Named + @RequestScoped` bean.

```
// Before
@ManagedBean
public class Login {
   ...
}

// After
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Login {
   ...
}
```

Everything works fine as long as I use `@ManagedBean`. `@Named` without `@RequestScoped` works but creates a new instance for each EL-expression. `@Named + @RequestScoped` however yields an exception: **Unable to add request scoped cache item when request cache is not active**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to add request scoped cache item when request cache is not active
    at org.jboss.weld.context.cache.RequestScopedBeanCache.addItem(RequestScopedBeanCache.java:51)
    at de.prosis.dafe.presentation.Login$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getUsername(Login$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    ...
```

Empty `beans.xml` does exist. Are there any gotchas or bugs that I'm not aware of? I bet I'm missing something but it does look like a bug. I googled the exception message but haven't found anything but the source of the class which raises it. Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
It is related with code I omitted. The login bean tries to invalidate the session in its constructor, which fails if it is a named bean (not always, if I spam F5 it seems to works after a few times) and works as a managed bean. Can somebody explain that behaviour?

```
public Login() {
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                session.invalidate();
            }
}
```

Code comes from that tutorial:
http://www.greenkode.com/2011/09/user-authentication-and-authorization-using-jaas-and-servlet-3-0-login/

Comment: Your bean must implement `java.io.Serializable`. Thanks to BalusC for pointing out that it won't fix the problem. Nevertheless, it is required for the bean to participate in CDI.

Comment: @SteveTaylor could you provide some documentation why Serializable is necessary for a bean to participate in CDI? Almost all examples of `@Named` + `@RequestScoped` are not Serializable. Thanks!

Comment: For RequestScoped it doesn't need to be Serializable.

Comment: Also not sure why you're doing this in a bean, seems like a filter or request listener would be better for the session stuff.

Comment: @LightGuard well that was part of the tutorial. I don't get why ManagedBean works and Named does not, but without the session invalidation everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by removing invalidation of the session in the constructor. I still don't know why @ManagedBean works and @Named does not.

Comment: Since the question somehow changed since I realized what's really going on (sscce ftw ;)) and I'm unable to delete this question, I voted for closing. I will accept any answer which explains why `@Named` does not work while `@ManagedBean` does.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  Switched from @ManagedBean (which was working) to @Named which didn't work.  I had a beans.xml file in WEB-INF which didn't solve the problem like most people suggest.  You can add @Stateless along with @Named to make it work for reasons I don't know!  If anyone can explain that I would love to hear it.

Anyway, I am guessing the 'real' way to make @Named work is this:
@Named will work if you import the correct @RequestScoped annotation; from the javax.enterprise.context package.  The @RequestScoped annotation from the javax.faces.bean package is not compatible with the @Named annotation.  If you omit the correct @RequestScoped from being alongside @Named the bean will fire but it won't read any properties.

ps.  I use Glassfish so I doubt it's a JBoss problem.

Comment: As you can see in my Q, I used the correct @RequestScoped annotation. That's a common source for errors, though.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that you are either **outside** of one of [these](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html_single/#d0e5377) scenarios or that JBoss AS 7 has another issues like [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3129) one.

BTW, a request scoped bean is not required to be serializable. Probably @SteveTaylor mixed it with session scoped beans.

Comment: Yep, only `@SessionScoped` and `@ApplicationScoped` seem to require to be serializable. I tried to provide a SSCCE but it seems as soon as I remove the jaas part everything works as expected. I'll check that!

Comment: A small, working example.. (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example). Impossible to find out with google :P

Answer (score -1):

For those still fighting with the issue, this worked for me (the reason why is still obscure)

I use GF4 with netbeans. Netbeans has also a great tabcompletion in the JSF pages that didn't behave coherently with the injections. I tested (currently) only the request-scope but I supose it's all in the package..

So here are all the combinations I used and there results (on top the solution)

### Best Solution

```
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped; 
import javax.inject.Named; 
//=> Injection ok - Tab Completion OK
```

---

### Other less or inadequate combinations (info)

```
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean; 
//=> Injection ok - Tab Completion NOK

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named; 
//=> Injection nok - Tab Completion OK 


import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
//=> Injection nok - Tab Completion OK 


import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
//=> Injection nok - Tab Completion OK


import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean; 
//=> Injection nok - Tab Completion NOK
```